# Gijgo grid field from object

Tags: javascript, json, gijgo-grid

I'm using Gijgo grid for first time.  I'm geting data by AJAX in Json format.

My data have a object.  How can I display object property in the grid.

Here an data sample :

```
{
    "Id" : 0,
    "FirstName":"John",
    "Enterprise": {
         "Name":"Company"
    }
    ...
}
```

Here how I init my grid :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#myGrid').grid({
              dataSource: 'MyGetMethod',
              uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
              columns: [
                  { field: 'Id', hidden: true },
                  { field: 'FirstName', title: 'FirstName', sortable: true },
                  { field: 'Enterprise.Name', width: 75, title: 'Company', sortable: true },
              ],
              pager: { limit: 5 }
          });
      });
</script>
```

How to display Field `Enterprise.Name`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This should work.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#myGrid').grid({
          dataSource: 'MyGetMethod',
          uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
          columns: [
              { field: 'Id', hidden: true },
              { field: 'FirstName', title: 'FirstName', sortable: true },
              { width: 75, title: 'Company', sortable: true , renderer: function (value, record) { return record.Enterprise.Name; }},
          ],
          pager: { limit: 5 }
      });
  });
```